# Request Mapping not working after upgrading to Spring boot 2.x

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following controller which worked well in Spring boot 1.x:

```
@Log4j2
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/delivery/{id}")
public class DeliveryController {

    @Autowired
    private DeliveryService deliveryService;

    /**
     * request mapping of http GET method.
     *
     * @param id    
     * @param serviceId id
     * @param accessKey password
     * @param request   use for log output only
     * @return MyDeliveryDto data exist 200(OK) : data not exist 204(NO_CONTENT)
     * @throws ServiceUnavailableException When the maintenance flag is true in the application.yml.
     * @throws UnAuthorizedException       serviceid and accessKey invalid.
     * @throws ForbiddenException          serviceID not registered in application.yml.
     */
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<MyDeliveryDto> get(@PathVariable Long id,
                                             String serviceId,
                                             String accessKey,
                                             HttpServletRequest request)
            throws ServiceUnavailableException, UnAuthorizedException, ForbiddenException {
        MyDeliveryDto dto = deliveryService.select(id, serviceId, accessKey);
        log.info("response dto : {}, serviceId : {}", dto, serviceId);
        if (Objects.isNull(dto)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<MyDeliveryDto>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

But after upgrading to Spring boot 2.0.4, I get the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018/08/10T10:35:59.459+0900",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/mydata-api/delivery/123"
}
```

Have I missed anything when migrating to the new version?

Comment: `@ResponseBody` is duplicate,need to remove it

Comment: yeah tried that too, still the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue - The context-path config has been moved to `server.servlet.context-path` so the old `server.context-path` is deprecated.